# Spring 3 MVC accessing HttpRequest from controller

Tags: spring-mvc, httprequest, httpsession, request-mapping

I would like to handle request and session attributes myself rather then leave it to spring `@SessionAttributes`, for login of cookies handling for example.

I just cant figure out how could I access the `HttpRequest` from within a controller, I need a way to go a layer above the `@RequestAttribute` and access the `HttpRequest` itself. With Stripes in used to do this by implementing an `ApplicationContext` and calling `getAttribute()`.

Also, passing the `HttpServletRequest` as parameter seems not to be working:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/") public String home(HttpServletRequest request){
    System.out.println(""+request.getSession().getCreationTime());
    return "home"; 
}
```

The above method does not print anything.

Do you have any advice on this?

Answer (score 228):

Spring MVC will give you the HttpRequest if you just add it to your controller method signature:

For instance:

```
/**
 * Generate a PDF report...
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/report/{objectId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody void generateReport(
        @PathVariable("objectId") Long objectId, 
        HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response) {

    // ...
    // Here you can use the request and response objects like:
    // response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    // response.getOutputStream().write(...);

}
```

As you see, simply adding the `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` objects to the signature makes Spring MVC to pass those objects to your controller method. You'll want the `HttpSession` object too.

EDIT: It seems that HttpServletRequest/Response are not working for some people under Spring 3. Try using Spring WebRequest/WebResponse objects as Eduardo Zola pointed out.

I strongly recommend you to have a look at the [list of supported arguments](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments) that Spring MVC is able to auto-magically inject to your handler methods.

Comment: Hi, thx for the hints, i dont know what i'm doing wrong but this isn't working: it does not prints anything:                             @RequestMapping(value="/")
 public String home(HttpServletRequest request){
 
  System.out.println(""+request.getSession().getCreationTime());
  
  return "home";
  
 }       This should pring the current amount pof millis but it does not, also annotating the method with @RequestBody does not change anything, any further advice? thx for this

Comment: Thanks @jjmontes for the link to Spring MVC's supported arguments!

Comment: I know next to nothing about Spring, but I had to add the `@Context` annotation before the argument in order to get them injected. Could be something new, I dunno, but figured I'd mention it.

Answer (score 92):

I know that is a old question, but...

You can also use this in your class:

```
@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest context;
```

And this will provide the current instance of `HttpServletRequest` for you use on your method.

Comment: Doesn't doing it this way prevent the controller bean from being a singleton?

Comment: Spring controllers are always singletons.

Comment: This feels wrong - what if the controller is handling more than one request at the given time? What is "current" request then?

Comment: This question have some explanations about you're asking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235794/how-does-spring-mvc-handle-multiple-users

Comment: It would be quite useful to have something like `getThreadLocalRequest()` in GWT's `RemoteServiceServlet` which always returns correct request even if it is executed in highly concurrent environment.

Comment: This is imho a better explanation of how application servers make some per-request data accessible to singletons via ThreadLocal variables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139571/scope-of-a-spring-controller-and-its-instance-variables . In any case, Autowiring the context to the controller is imho not the best practice,and I'd rather pass context as an argument to the controller method.

Comment: @sbk controller methods are handling always single request per invocation. This is how HTTP works, can't even imagine how multiple requests may happen in single invocation.

Answer (score 6):

Another way is to use `RequestContextHolder` like: (Since: 2.0)

RequestContextHolder Holder class to expose the web request in the form of a thread-bound RequestAttributes object. The request will be inherited by any child threads spawned by the current thread if the inheritable flag is set to true.

```
HttpServletRequest req = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/") public String home(HttpServletRequest request){
    System.out.println("My Attribute :: "+request.getAttribute("YourAttributeName"));
    return "home"; 
}
```