# Spring MVC pass a list of values into controller from JSP page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

If I have a HTML in a `<form>` like this:

```
    <input type="text" value="someValue1" name="myValues"/>
    <input type="text" value="someValue2" name="myValues"/>
    <input type="text" value="someValue3" name="myValues"/>
    <input type="text" value="someValue4" name="myValues"/>
```

I know that in servlets I am able to get values using:

```
String[] values = request.getParameterValues("myValues");
```

How can I do something similar using Spring MVC?

Comment: Spring MVC is built on top of servlets, so the request.getParameter is still available in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parameters are passed as arguments to the method bound to your controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.POST) // or GET
public String foo(@RequestParam("myValues") String[] myValues) {
    // Processing
    return "view";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

You already have `HttpServletRequest request` in spring web MVC. We can get it using the same i.e. using

```
 String[] values = request.getParameterValues("myValues");
```

Also you can use [ServletRequestUtils](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/ServletRequestUtils.html) to read request parameters in Spring like :

```
String[] values = ServletRequestUtils.getRequiredStringParameters(request, "myValues");
```

See how to access Http request : [Spring 3 MVC accessing HttpRequest from controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504258/spring-3-mvc-accessing-httprequest-from-controller)

For annotation based approach: See Alex's answer.

Answer (score 0):

In jsp i would like:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%> <!-- Add taglib in beginning of the page.-->

<!-- In body the html -->
<form:form  action="/foo" method="post" commandName="MyValues">
  <input type="text" value="someValue1" name="myValues1"/>
  <input type="text" value="someValue2" name="myValues2"/>
  <input type="text" value="someValue3" name="myValues3"/>
  <input type="text" value="someValue4" name="myValues4"/>
</form:form>
```

See references in section 13.9. Using Spring's form tag library tag explains, in link: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html

The controller is part of the same friend Alex answered.