# Pass a list of li from client to Spring MVC controller

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc

I would like to send a list of values to a Spring controller in a submission. The list changes dinamically in the client. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602061/spring-mvc-pass-a-list-of-values-into-controller-from-jsp-page) but only works with input, because I can not put a name in the tag li.

```
<ul id="paramselected" class="paramsnav" class="dropdown">
    <li class="ui-widget-content selected">value1</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content selected">value2</li>
    ...                 
</ul>
```

Are there anyway to achieve it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: want to sent whole list or only selected single value(at a time )?

Comment: Check out the [following](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit) looks like what you need.

Comment: I would like to send all values in the list together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ul id="paramselected" class="paramsnav" class="dropdown">
  <li class="ui-widget-content selected"><input type="hidden" value="value1" name="liContent">value1</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content selected"><input type="hidden" value="value2" name="liContent">value2</li>  
  <li class="ui-widget-content selected"><input type="hidden" value="value3" name="liContent">value3</li>              
</ul>
```

And you controller shuold be like :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/actionName")
  public String getLiValues(HttpServletRequest request){
    String[] liValues = request.getParameterValues("liContent");
  }
```

And your array is ready with the li values.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `<ul>` data is not sent to the server because it is not a user input component.

check below link

[Trying to get some kind of dynamic, unordered list to send the order to servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23713329/trying-to-get-some-kind-of-dynamic-unordered-list-to-send-the-order-to-servlet)

but if you want to send all values you can send it by javascript or ajax by fetching `<li>` values in javascript and send to servlet.

Answer (score 1):

You can Post the data using a javascript POST(with an `XMLHttpRequest`), retrieve the data from the list and send it.

Answer (score 1):

Use **jquery** for getting the value of **li** tag ,  after that make a array and call the controller with  array as a request  parameter.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Normal behavior is that only input elements are posted to the servlet from `<form>` submit. You can rather post it through `jquery`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        var arr = [];
        // get the text from li's
        $('#paramselected li').each(function(index) {
          arr.push($(this).text());
        });
        $.post("URLMapped",
        {
          liValues: arr; // arr contains your li texts
        },
        function(data,status){
            // your response here
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use js or jquery ajax request for this. You can find all li value different at js, after that you describe `var obj`. which has li values and call ajax method  :

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        mimeType: 'application/json',
        async: true,
        url: url,
        data: obj,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);

        }
    });
```