# Servlet to Spring Servlet: Is it possible to implement GET method using Spring's HttpRequestHandler?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, servlets

I'm updating a regular Servlet to a Spring kind Servlet. To accomplish this I followed [these instructions](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/251636/How-to-inject-Spring-beans-into-Servlets) that say I should implement `HttpRequestHandler`. That's great and works for my Servlet because right now I only call it using POST method.

But now I'm curious about what happens if I want to implement the GET method too. In a regular Servlet I have:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
...
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
...
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
...

}
```

But when implementing HttpRequestHandler I have:

```
public class MyServlet implements HttpRequestHandler {
...
   public void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
...
}
```

Reading the [official documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/HttpRequestHandler.html) it says that it only supports POST by default, but couldn't find a way to implement GET. Other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504258/spring-3-mvc-accessing-httprequest-from-controller) gave me an idea of using a Controller that could receive a GET request and then call the `HttpRequestHandler`, but that didn't seemed very neat to me.

Can anyone tell me if it is possible and how do I do it? If possible reference some docs :)

Comment: The documentation says that request handlers normally handle only POST requests, not that it doesn't support GET requests: what happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

this is just a guess but can't you just use request parameter to determine the method and act accordingly further in handleRequest method?

Comment: I didn't try it... sounds good. I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: Mention the HttpServletRequest.getMethod() function or show code using it, to make your answer __explicit__.