# Can we get HttpRequest Object in Controller in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

Is it possible that I can get HttpRequest object in my Controller class in Spring MVC ?

```
@Controller
public class ContactController {

    @Autowired
    private ContactService contactService; 

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String displayLoginPage(@ModelAttribute("login") Login login, BindingResult result) {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Comment: It is good to ask questions however I wonder what stops you from little search on google or stackoverflow. a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504258/spring-3-mvc-accessing-httprequest-from-controller

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
public String displayLoginPage(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute("login") Login login, BindingResult result){
    return "login";
}
```