# How to get HttpServletRequest object inside a controller

Tags: java, class, spring-mvc

I've written a controller class and an action method like the

```
@Controller
public class Controller
{
    @RequestParam("/test.htm")
    public String action(Model model)
    {
         //Something
    }
}
```

How to get `HttpServletRequest` object in action's method body?

Comment: you might want to take a look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504258/spring-3-mvc-accessing-httprequest-from-controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the instance of `HttpServletRequest` by passing a reference in your action method:

```
@Controller
public class Controller
{
    @RequestParam("/test.htm")
    public String action(Model model, HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        //Something
        try {
            request.getParameter("user_name"); //write in try-catch block
        } catch(ServletException ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring MVC readily avails  HttpServletRequest  , HttpServletResponse and many other classes for processing:

Directly add HttpServletRequest   in your method argument as below :

```
@RequestParam("/test.htm")
public String action(Model model ,  HttpServletRequest request)
{
     //Something
}
```