# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am beginner to Spring MVC Framework. I started to learn Spring two days back. For learning purpose I am developing one simple Application. i.e., Get user input from form and display values in another page. I got an Exception " java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute". I cant figure out what's wrong in my code. I searched Google and tried many solution but the problem is still here.

Here is my view
index.jsp

```
<form:form action="/addDisplay" method="POST">
     <form:label path="name"><h3>Name</h3></form:label>
     <form:input type="text" path="name" cssClass="form-control text-center" required="required"/>

     <form:label path="age"><h3>Age</h3></form:label>
     <form:input type="number" path="age" cssClass="form-control text-center" required="required"/>

     <form:label path="work"><h3>Work Place</h3></form:label>
     <form:input type="text" path="work" cssClass="form-control text-center" required="required"/>

     <form:label path="designation"><h3>Designation</h3></form:label>
     <form:input type="text" path="designation" cssClass="form-control text-center" required="required"/>

     <form:label path="area"><h3>Area</h3></form:label>
     <form:input type="text" path="area" placeholder="Where Are You From?" cssClass="form-control text-center" required="required"/>

     <form:label path="mobile"><h3>Mobile Number</h3></form:label>
     <form:input type="number" path="mobile" placeholder="Your Mobile Number.!" cssClass="form-control text-center" required="required"/>

     <form:label path="email"><h3>Email</h3></form:label>
     <form:input type="email" path="email" placeholder="Your Email Id..!" cssClass="form-control text-center" required="required"/>
     <br/>
     <input type="submit" value="Generate" class="btn btn-success form-control"/>
</form:form>
```

myself.jsp

```
<div style="margin-top: 3%; font-size: 20px;">
    <h3>My Introduction.</h3>
       <p>
        Hi, I am ${name} my age is ${age} and I am from ${area}. I am working as a ${designation}  
        in ${work}. You can contact me in my mobile ${mobile} and You can also shoot mail to 
        ${email}.
       </p>
</div>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SpringWork</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.infofaces.spring.form" />
        <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix">
                <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
            </property>
            <property name="suffix">
                <value>.jsp</value>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
            <property name="basename" value="com/infofaces/spring/form/MySelf" />
        </bean>

        <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

        <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

My model name is Myself.java and it has private variables and getter, setter methods for that variable. Here is my controller.

HelloController.java

```
package com.infofaces.spring.form;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/display", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView display() {
        return new ModelAndView("myself", "command", new MySelf());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/addDisplay", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addDisplay(@ModelAttribute("command") MySelf myself, ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("name",myself.getName());
        model.addAttribute("age", myself.getAge());
        model.addAttribute("work", myself.getWork());
        model.addAttribute("designation", myself.getDesignation());
        model.addAttribute("mobile", myself.getMobile());
        model.addAttribute("email", myself.getEmail());
        return "myself";
    }
}
```

Full Stack Trace.

```
type Exception report

message java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:465)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:179)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:199)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:130)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:120)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:90)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:103)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f0(index_jsp.java:265)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(index_jsp.java:170)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:105)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Please help to find problem in my code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know you have solved this problem or not. If not, then you can try my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You are  missing `commandName="command"` in your  index.jsp file .

```
<form:form action="/addDisplay" method="POST" commandName="command" >
```

Make sure that `command` object is available in your request attribute before index.jsp is being processed.   I hope this would work.

EDIT : As you said in comment  when you call index.jsp definatily you will get  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute` error.

Because when your jsp is being rendered command object not available  for that first you have to make request to controller , put object into Model name it `command` and then provide view name index.jsp

For example :

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView display() {
    return new ModelAndView("index", "command", new MySelf());
}
```

Now  you won't get that error. I hope this would work.

Comment: command is a default object we dont need to mention that right? But ok. I tried that also but this exception still remains. I also tried  ModelAttribute="command".'

Comment: which url are you calling broswer ? is it index.jsp directly ? or you are calling /display    ?

Comment: index.jsp directly..

Comment: thats why you are getting  that error .  I have edited  answer, go through it.

Comment: I tried this, still I have the same exception `Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of forwarding to your index.jsp via *welcome-files* list, you should add

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index"/>
```

to your mvc configuration, and an accompanying controller mapping where you will add the command object to the model, e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("command", new MySelf()); 
    return "index";
}
```

Your problem is that you got forwarded to the `index.jsp` via welcome-files and the request wasn't process by spring. Yet you use spring's `form:form` which if not otherwise renamed via *commandName* or *modelAttribute* attributes expects an object with the key *command* inside the request attributes

Comment: I tried this but still I have the same issue..

Comment: I think that Rembo and I go about the same solution, and as he mentions, make sure that you remove the welcome-list

Comment: Yeah. I removed welcome-list

Answer (score 0):

you have used spring form tag in index.jsp where a command/modelAttribute object should be available as a request parameter to bind form data, which is you have not done and the exception message what it says.

To solve this problem follow below steps:

**Step 1:**
Remove all welcome-file-list from web.xml.

**Step 2:**
add "/" into display GET handler.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/display"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView display() {
    return new ModelAndView("myself", "command", new MySelf());
 }
```

**Step 3:**
add modelAttribute name in form tag:

```
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addDisplay" 
           method="POST" 
           modelAttribute="command">
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider, you have HTML form like below

**Login Form:**

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
    <body>    
        <form:form action="doLogin.html" method="post" modelAttribute="loginEntity" name="loginForm">
            <!-- Form inputs -->
        </form:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

You want to perform login by calling action `doLogin.html`. As you have specified `modelAttribute="loginEntity"` attribute in Spring form which is created using above code snippet. **You must set an empty Object of model which hold required request params in Controller.** Observe below code carefully:-

**Model Class:**

```
public class Login {
    private String  userName    = "";
    private String  password    = "";
    // getters/setters
}
```

**Controller Class:**

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/showLoginForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showLoginForm() {
        System.out.println("In login form...");

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("login");
        mv.addObject("loginEntity", new Login());
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/doLogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView doLogin(@ModelAttribute Login login, BindingResult result) {

        String userName = login.getUserName();
        String password = login.getPassword();

        if ("OO7".equals(userName) && "OO7".equals(password)) {
            return new ModelAndView("forward:success.html");
        } else {
            return new ModelAndView("forward:failure.html");
        }
    }
}
```

In the controller, I have added an empty model `new Login()` for the modelAttribute `loginEntity` in the `showLoginForm()` function. This will map all the request parameters & allow to set &/or retrieve values from them.

Now, you can add link to your `index.jsp` which will give a call to Controller to display `login.jsp` just like below :-

**Index Page:**

```
<html>
    <body>    
        <ul>
            <li><a href="showLoginForm.html">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Overall Request Flow:**

1. At application start `index.jsp` will load having a link to `login.jsp`.
2. On click of link `<a href="showLoginForm.html">Login</a>` a call to controller is made & it **searches for request mapping *showLoginForm*** in it.
3. Once he found the specified mapping, he proceed further to display `login.jsp` page.
4. On submit of the login form, a request for `doLogin.html` is made. Once again control goes to Controller to search for `doLogin` request mapping.
5. Once he found `doLogin` request mapping, depending on the login credentials, you will be redirected to either `success.jsp` or `failure.jsp` page.

**NOTE:**

1. Don't mix `commandName` & `modelAttribute` in Spring form. You are only allow to use any of them.
2. If you forgot to add empty model in the Controller, then you will face below exception

   ```
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for 
   bean name 'loginEntity' available as request attribute
   ```

I hope this will clear your idea of using `@ModelAttribute` in Spring.

Comment: What is the purpose of empty Model.? Is there is any other way to map request from form withoutl that empty Model.?

Comment: Empty model maps all the fields in UI with member variables in POJO with the default values specified for each member.

Comment: I don't need like href link to display login form and it also calls that empty model.. I want to display the login form directly without using link..

Comment: Then no need to write `modelAttribute` for ur login form, instead create a simple login form & access login credentials from `HttpServletRequest & HttpServletResponse` objects in the method directly & validate it. Or u can also `Autowire HttpServletRequest` to fetch login credentials.

Comment: How can I use `HttpServletRequest` & `HttpServletResponse` objects in Spring MVC framework.?

Comment: Look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504258/spring-3-mvc-accessing-httprequest-from-controller) & [MKYong article](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-http-request-header-in-java/).

Comment: Ok.. If I am using `HttpServletRequest` there is no need of JSP Form Tag Library. Right?

Comment: Yes. U just need then simple form without any tag library.

Comment: Have u tried with simple login form ? Will u able to proceed in ur work with that ?

Comment: No. This is also a simple form work. Get details in form and display that in another page thats all..

Comment: What do u want exactly, to get rid of this error or something else ? Will u please elaborate ? How do u want ur system to call pages ? I m using this pattern & it's working.