# How to design the API such that it reads HTTP header if parameters are not present?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In a controller class,

I have one method

```
@RequestMapping(value="test", method={RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.PUT})
@ResponseBody
public String testApp(@RequestParam String priceA, @RequestBody String valueOfProduct) throws Exception {  

}
```

My client is sending prices to my App as POST requests for processing.

Now client (which is not under my control) is planning to send the price value as a request parameter and another client is planning to send price in requestheader.

The trick is:
If it is present in requestheader it wont be present in requestparameter.

So I have to design it such that my server code works fine in both cases.

Kindly let me know which design would be the best.

Will it be

```
@RequestMapping(value="test", method={RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.PUT})
@ResponseBody
public String testApp(@RequestParam String priceA, @RequestHeader("PRICE") String priceAFromAnother,  @RequestBody String valueOfProduct) throws Exception {  

}
```

But above logic wont work as @RequestParam  wont be available all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried searching by your own first?
Take a look that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504258/spring-3-mvc-accessing-httprequest-from-controller) answer.

Comment: Yes, I had checked. But I have been asked to keep the same signature itself. I have permissions to add a argument. That is why I cannot take the httpservletrequest approach. Else I know I can easily get the values using httpservletrequest.getParam() and httpservletrequest.getHeader().    The challenge is making the changes with minimum changes to design and unit testcases.

Answer (score 0):

If you **know** the header to search for, you could add a request filter (HttpServletRequestWrapper) that pre-process the request.  Here is simple example [Modify request parameter with servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413129/modify-request-parameter-with-servlet-filter)

**NOTE: I would caution you that this methodology is not maintainable if your parameter set/api is going to grow over time.**

Comment: Mine is a spring controller class. So If I follow this approach, it would force me to make drastic changes in design of public String testApp(@RequestParam String priceA, @RequestBody String valueOfProduct) throws Exception {  

}        This will create problems for my client sending POST request right. I have no control over client code. Kindly advice.