# Submitting form without fixed number of inputs

Tags: spring, forms, jsp

In my JSP file I have form with flexible number of inputs - user has a possibility to add or delete inputs of a form(I did it using Javascript). Therefore form hasn't got a fixed number of inputs. This is required. Now I want to create controller taking these parameters but... I can't specify how many of inputs there will be. They're all Strings. Is there any way to pass these inputs into a controller? I'm using Spring and JSP for the views.

Comment: What about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504258/spring-3-mvc-accessing-httprequest-from-controller

Answer (score 1):

It is no simplest variant, but anyway:

```
 $('#yourInputForm').submit(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();

var arr = []

$('#yourInputForm').find('input').each(function () {
                arr.push($(this).val());
        });
});
```

Pay attention, I didn't check if val() is empty.
Inside this function you can send you arr with ajax to your controller.