# How to create a bean that takes HttpServletRequest as constructor argument?

Tags: spring, spring-aop, keycloak, applicationcontext

Is this possible to define a Spring bean in applicationContext.xml that takes an instance of HttpRequest as a constructor argument?

The bean I'm trying to create is an instance of `org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.facade.WrappedHttpServletRequest`. The reason behind this is that I want to use Spring AOP to intercept a method that's invoked from that class. Is this possible?

That's the constructor code:

```
public WrappedHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Assert.notNull(request, "HttpServletRequest required");
    this.request = request;
}
```

Comment: You can autowire it, @Autowired private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

this is considered as bad practice though, the recommended way is to somehow pass it as request parameter to controller
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504258/spring-3-mvc-accessing-httprequest-from-controller

Comment: Thank you Borislav. I changed the approach, but will remember this next time I need to do something like that again.